# Want logs in console but not in development.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, ruby-on-rails-4.1

For several reasons I don't want Rails to write log info to development.log.

How can I accomplish that but still output log info in the console?

Inserting the following to config/environments/development.rb stopped logs to both development.log and the console:

```
config.log_level = :fatal
```

Answer (score 2):

Per this comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19082842/4638378):

> you can log to STDOUT in development.rb:
>
> config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)