# git push master not working files too large

Tags: git, github

When I try using the git push origin master command terminal throws an error saying files too large.

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 44baa062afa347dd9f954a2f0809b535
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File vendor/bundle/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17-x86_64-darwin-
12/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/libv8_base.a is 127.87 MB; 
this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
To git@github.com:aTylerRice/mixeddrinks.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:aTylerRice/mixeddrinks.git'
```

Is this because I shouldn't be including certain files to be pushed? If so how do I ignore those files when pushing?

Comment: YES. Have you looked at the url in 3rd line? They have a help there.

Comment: The 3rd line goes to: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Github file size limit changed 6/18/13. Can't push now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382375/github-file-size-limit-changed-6-18-13-cant-push-now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should a line to the .gitignore at the top level of your project that just reads

`vendor`

That will cause git to completely ignore the contents of the `vendor` directory.  You probably want that.

(Also, an aside: you might want to understand *why* that `vendor/bundle` directory even exists.  That's usually a sign that you're running Bundler in deployment mode, i.e., `bundle install --deployment`  That's *slightly* unusual for a developer to be doing in his or her "personal" build.  Do you know why you, or your team, is doing that?)

Comment: I the vendor line to my .gitignore file and it still seems to be including those files.  Tbh I'm just a college student that builds these things for fun and I didn't know there was even a deployment mode. Should I change it to a different mode?

Answer (score 0):

Think about this:
in log i see libv8-3.11.8.17-x86_64-darwin-
12 - it lib for OS X, but on the web server you likely use ubuntu/debian/freebsd kernel
for what in you github repository store the lib for kernel different from you server.