# How to remove big files from local repo for successful push

Tags: linux, git, file, github

I've just created local repo and commited all files from the root dir.
But GiutHub failed to receive a push to remote hub cause of giant file limitations:

```
[srv50213@cl10-m htdocs]$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 17875, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17645/17645), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17875/17875), 413.33 MiB | 3.69 MiB/s, done.
Total 17875 (delta 5496), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: warning: File 20140924.srv50213_tarex.dump is 82.14 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: ac437f9f600e8418e6bf5065e472204c
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File htdocs/2014-10-09-10:40-site-archive.zip is 227.12 MB; th exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
To git@github.com:igorsavinkin/tarex.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:igorsavinkin/tarex.git'
```

after that I tried to remove those files from local repo but failed, according to this [instruction](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/#fixing-the-problem):

```
[srv50213@cl10-m htdocs]$ git rm --cached 20140924.srv50213_tarex.dump
fatal: pathspec 'htdocs/20140924.srv50213_tarex.dump' did not match any files

[srv50213@cl10-m ~]$ git rm --cached 20140924.srv50213_tarex.dump
rm '20140924.srv50213_tarex.dump'

[srv50213@cl10-m ~]$ git rm --cached htdocs/2014-10-09-10:40-site-archive.zip
fatal: pathspec 'htdocs/2014-10-09-10:40-site-archive.zip' did not match any files
[srv50213@cl10-m ~]$ git rm --cached 2014-10-09-10:40-site-archive.zip
fatal: pathspec '2014-10-09-10:40-site-archive.zip' did not match any files
```

Even though I amend:

```
[srv50213@cl10-m ~]$ git commit --amend -CHEAD
[master 35dc27d] remove file1.txt
6 files changed, 1249 insertions(+), 2072 deletions(-)
delete mode 100644 20140924.srv50213_tarex.dump
delete mode 100644 20140924.srv50213_yupe.dump
delete mode 100644 htdocs/2014-10-09-10:40-site-archive.zip
```

when I want to push it again I get the same result:

```
[srv50213@cl10-m ~]$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 17875, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17645/17645), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17875/17875), 413.33 MiB | 3.63 MiB/s, done.
Total 17875 (delta 5499), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: warning: File 20140924.srv50213_tarex.dump is 82.14 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 7abab285207c27988ceddd39f61f25cd
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File htdocs/2014-10-09-10:40-site-archive.zip is 227.12 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
To git@github.com:igorsavinkin/tarex.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:igorsavinkin/tarex.git'
```

How to resolve this quest with 2 big files stored/stuck in the local repo?
When I want to remove them from git by `git rm --cached 2014-10-09-10:40-site-archive.zip` should an instance of it be in the corresponding folder of working copy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Github file size limit changed 6/18/13. Can't push now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382375/github-file-size-limit-changed-6-18-13-cant-push-now)

Comment: @ John Zwinck, the given solution did not help me. As `[srv50213@cl10-m ~]$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch htdocs/2014-10-09-10:40-site-archive.zip' HEAD
Cannot rewrite branch(es) with a dirty working directory.` I've turned to clear the whole local repo and add into it anew: `$ git clean -f` but again after adding folder into repo anew i got the same issues with the same big files...