# Git error when trying to sync fom Visual Studio 2015 (hook error update)

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I am working on a branch and when i am trying to sync my commit i am getting the following error in the outpubt box of visual studio:

```
The following errors were reported during push: refs/heads/master, pre-receive hook declined
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github file size limit changed 6/18/13. Can't push now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382375/github-file-size-limit-changed-6-18-13-cant-push-now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you have an issue when you are trying to push something, is there anything else in the output box in visual studio?

Also did you customize your hook? If so, have a look here at the Git hook documentation: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Edit:
Ok in that case if you dont need these files, yo can try to ignore them.

Create a file '.gitignore' that contains the path or files that need to not be pushed

Comment: In the output I also have a message saying that "this exceeds GitHub’s file size limit of 100 MB"