# Git LFS not working

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm having issues getting Git LFS to track my large files properly (similar issue reported here: [Git LFS refused to track my large files properly, until I did the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518688/git-lfs-refused-to-track-my-large-files-properly-until-i-did-the-following)).

In my specific case, I am trying to push a directory composed of multiple subdirectories, each of which has files of a specific type that I would like to track.  The extensions for these file types are `.bed`, `.Bed`, and `.sorted`.  Here was the recipe that I followed:

I did `git add .`, then `git commit -m "initial commit"`, then issued the respective tracking commands (e.g., `git lfs track ".bed"`), and then did `git push origin master`.

However, I still received multiple error commands ending in "`this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`".  I've already gone through practically every available Stack Overflow post on this topic (e.g.., [git lfs not working properly for files larger than 100MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258605/git-lfs-not-working-properly-for-files-larger-than-100mb)), so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these [instructions](https://github.com/github/git-lfs), first you need to *track*, then you can *add* and *commit*. I followed a similar instruction for bitbucket and it worked.

When you *add* and *commit* before *track*, you are probably commiting in your repo instead of the lfs repo.

Comment: Did you remove the file from the tree before adding again? You can do this using git rm --cached *filename*. Then proceed with git add file.bed and git commit.

Comment: Well I followed the Github instructions perfectly, and then when it was time for `git push origin master`, I received: `Git LFS: (0 of 671 files, 100 skipped) 0 B / 8.88 GB, 2.84 GB skipped`, then followed by a `U` (whatever this means!), and then a repetitive line of `Git LFS: (0 of 671 files, 100 skipped) 0 B / 8.88 GB, 2.84 GB skipped`.  And the program hangs up.  Like nothing happens whatsoever, so I'm forced to do ctrl-c to break out.  Note that I do successfully get output from `git lfs ls-files`, so I've narrowed my problem down to the last step.  What could be wrong?

Comment: I did some tests and it worked here, but only with files smaller than 100MB. I was not able to reproduce the file being skipped. However, the error that you described is related to 100MB limit. [Here](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/) it says that 100MB is the hard limit and no push is allowed in such conditions. Have you tried to push smaller files?

Comment: But isn't that the point of Git LFS, i.e., to push files larger than 100 MB (via pointers)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to remove all cached files because you have quite a few large files then you can use:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Make sure you include that period to signal you want all files uncached.

Answer (score -1):

I had exacly the same issue. I later realized that the large files were indeed uploaed via lfs just like showed "....skipped..." . But the large files still exist in the git commit history.
How I solved it was to use `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <file/dir>' HEAD` (note you need to replace  by the filename of your large file) .This will filter your large file records in the history. After this, I could `git push origin master`, no more error.